# Doing inner join with Hibernate and JSP

Tags: hibernate, jsp, hql, inner-join, dao

I have three tables that I need to do an inner join though I know how to do this in SQL editor, I'm not sure how it works with Hibernate.

To fully explain, I have a:

- Skill (where all questions are located)
- Section (section titles, such as Part 1. Part 2)
- Skillset (acts as the subject, Motor Skills, Language etc.)

I have separate DAOs, each of them with codes like this
This is my Skill Dao:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import softdev.asese.models.SkillModel;
import softdev.asese.utils.HibernateUtil;

public class SkillDao
{

    public List<SkillModel> getSkill() {
        List<SkillModel> list = new ArrayList<SkillModel>();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();
            list = session.createQuery("from SkillModel").list();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

My Section Dao and Skillset Dao are just the same with this, differing the query and naming of course. They are all connected and references with each other. The Skillset is connected to Section, and the Section is connected to Skill.
I also have an Assessment where the Skill is connected. This would be the examination paper. What I need is to display each title, section, and question properly and in order with this Dao. So far, I have not succeeded and have only managed to load all questions (w/o sectioning and title) through the Skill

```
<% SkillDao sDao = new SkillDao();
    List<SkillModel> skList = sDao.getSkill();
%>

<tbody>
    <% for(SkillModel s : skList) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= s.getSkillName() %><br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="ans" value="Independent">Independent<br>
            <input type="radio" name="ans" value="Emerging">Emerging<br>
            <input type="radio" name="ans" value="No response">No Response<br><br><br></td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of the relations are one to many and your entity objects look like this:

```
@Entity
public class SkillSet {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Section> sections;
    public List<Section> getSections() { return sections; }
}

@Entity
public class Section {
    @OneToMany
    private List<SkillModel> skillModels;
    @ManyToOne
    private SkillSet skillSet;
    public SkillSet getSkillSet() { return skillSet; }
}

@Entity
public class SkillModel {
    @ManyToOne
    private Section section;
    public Section getSection() { return section; }
}
```

Then the SkillSet and Section objects can be obtained as follows:

```
List<SkillModel> skList = sDao.getSkill();
for(SkillModel model : skList) {
    Section s = model.getSection();
    SkillSet ss = s.getSkillSet();
}
```

Comment: The Skillset and Section are one-to-many meaning, one skillset can have many sections and the section to skill are also in one to many, one section can contain many questions. Also, the skill only has the foreign key of Section.

the id depends on what skillset I want to show

My SQL query is this:
SELECT Section.section_id, Skill.skill_name 
FROM Skill 
INNER JOIN Section 
ON Section.section_id=Skill.section_id 
INNER JOIN skillset 
ON Skillset.skillset_id=Section.skillset_id;
WHERE skillset.skillset_id=(WHAT SKILL SET)

Comment: If the relations are one to many instead of one to one you should just need to replace the annotations with `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`. JPA gives you the inner joins for free, just call a getter to get the Section from the SkillModel. There should be no need to execute a query. See an example of a bidirectional one to many relation: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jpa/one-to-many-bidirectional-mapping-in-jpa/